# BeautifulSoup methods

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, data-mining

I had install BeautifulSoup
but when I use any function in it I get the same error below

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

I am trying to do webscraping for website.

Comment: I think you will need to show your code that illustrates the error - we don't know what you are calling "find" on.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Based on error you used `find_all()` method (or similar one) somewhere in your code

```
info = soup.find_all("div", class_="div_class")
```

And you tried to find something in this search result

```
info.find("div", class_="some_other_div_class")
```

`find_all()` returns ResultSet object which inherits from a basic python list, so in order to use `find()` you need to use for loop:

```
for _ in info:
    _.find("div", class_="some_other_div_class")
```